# How to prevent a user from accessing a specific schema?

Tags: mysql, schema, privileges

I have a server, that was created for me.
On it there is a schema called "test".

I've logged in with root user, and created a new schema called "WEB".

```
create schema WEB;
```

What I want to do now, is to have a user, that can only see that new schema.

So I created a user like so:

```
create user webtestuser identified by 'webtestuser';

grant select, insert, update, delete on WEB.* to webtestuser;
```

The problem is that when I log in with the new user, I can still see the "test" schema. Even when I 'revoke all' on the user, that schema is still visable.

Anything I'm missing here?

Thanks !

Comment: Please can you login as that user and post the output of the command `SHOW GRANTS;`

Comment: Have you tried revoking privileges to test schema for user and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default mysql comes shipped with some grants foro the test schemas defined. They are `ALL ON test` to all users and also `ALL ON test\_%` to all users (`test\_%` matches stuff like `test_foo`, `test_123`)

Because of the way they're defined I can't see a way of removing these grants using the `REVOKE ... FROM` syntax so you'll have to use the following:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db IN("test","test\_%") AND User="" AND Host="%";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```